# StringIndexOutOfBoundsException in String.substring()

Tags: java

I've been having an issue with my code. It works fine and does what it is supposed to, but then it throws this error when it completes a certain segment and won't continue with the rest of the program afterward:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 42
    at java.lang.Sting.substring(Uknown Source)
    at SimplifyBinary.main(SimplifyBinary.java:32)
```

I've isolated the problem code segment and pasted it here:

```
try{
    //Turn input text file (binaryfile) into String
    String binarycode = new Scanner(new File(binaryfile)).next();
    int psn1 = 0;
    int psn2 = 2;
    //While loop that scans input String and replaces contents every two characters
    while (psn1 >= 0){
        String read = binarycode.substring(psn1, psn2);
        String convert1 = read.replace("1", "A");
        String convert2 = convert1.replace("0", "B");
        //Create new text file
        File converted = new File("convert1-"+binaryfile);
        //Write changes to new text file
        BufferedWriter output;
        output = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(converted, true));
        output.append(convert2);
        output.close();
        //Add 2 to each psn to move on to the next two characters in String for next loop
        psn1 = psn1+2;
        psn2 = psn2+2;
        //While loop repeats until psn1 returns -1 when the String ends
    }
}
catch (IOException e){
}
```

Is there something I did wrong here? Is there something missing or is there something that should not be there?

Comment: The code is attempting to access an index that isn't part of a collection.  (Specifically a character that isn't part of a string when calling `.substring()`.)  When you run the code in a debugger, what specific line throws the error?  What are the runtime values when that happens?

Comment: You do `while(psn1 >= 0)`, and then only ever increase `psn1`. When did you expect that condition to not be true any more?

Comment: That error is not unusual, that is pretty common when you learn arrays. If you show me a developer who never generated IndexOutOfBounds error, I will salute you.

Comment: As pointed out, you have an infinite loop that will eventually call indexes that exceed the length of your string and throw an exception. Try checking that psn2 is less than the length of your string instead.